# Port working without being put in IPTables

Tags: linux, debian, iptables

I recently installed a web service on my linux box (Sinusbot) and the web interface appears to be working without forwarding 8087 through IPTables, is this normal behaviour?

I feel like this means any port could be accessed through my server.

Answer (score 0):

If the packet reaches the end of a default chain – that is, if it didn't match any rules in INPUT – then it will use whatever action was set as the chain's "policy" (`iptables -P` or the `:INPUT ACCEPT` line).

In your case, INPUT consists entirely of port-specific accept rules but doesn't have any catch-all rule at the end. So all other packets are accepted as well, because the policy for INPUT was also set to "ACCEPT".